# Desktop items disappear every other start

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xfce, symbolic-link, amd-graphics

Since a few days, I am using a secondary display on my desktop computer. Ever since I attached the second display, the desktop icons (Home and trash folders as well as all drives and devices) disappear completely every other start (they are **not** moved to the secondary display).

After a reboot, they may or may not show up on the primary display's desktop (I wasn't able to figure out the cause of this and why they won't appear sometimes).

Another quirk I noticed is that my secondary display is shown as #1 in the display management screen and the primary display (although correctly marked as "primary") is displayed as #2, however this does not seem to affect the functionality in any other way.

I'm currently using Xfce 4 and an AMD Radeon R7 360 GPU with the displays connected to the DVI-I (primary) and HDMI (secondary) ports, respectively.

Comment: Used to happen to me a lot but not since kernel upgrade. When wallpaper cycled built in display was refreshed. Try changing wallpaper next missing icon  boot maybe?

Comment: That didn't work for me, unfortunately. Changing the wallpaper does't bring back the missing icons. The only way I've found to do this from a running system is to disable the second monitor in the settings and set it up again.